# Jenkins - Multijob : Phase job blocks if MultiJob parent comes in the queue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a multi job job say 'A', 'A' defines three phases,

1. Phase 1 - Run job 'B'
2. Phase 2 - Run job 'C','D','E'
3. Phase 3 - Run job 'F' - clean up job

I am facing a problem wherein when 'B' runs, it sometime times blocks if 'A' comes in build queue. So this becomes a deadlock for me, 
'A' build 1 runs which builds 'B' build 1. However, 'A' build 2 comes in pipeline (due to scm change or upstream project change).  'B' waits endlessly since 'A' build 2 is in waiting queue.

'A' build 1 -----waits for--> 'B' build 1 -------blocked by -------> 'A' build 2 in build queue

Please help.

Thanks

---

I have raised a [JIRA](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41587) in jenkins project.